# Very short story that involves time travel, sea-people, and a post-apocalyptic world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Years ago I read this story that I can't remember the name of. I asked about this on Reddit but no one answered.

The story is from a point of view from a group of sea-people many years into the future. One of them comes across a time traveler who was sent by his professor to investigate whether a nuclear war would happen. The sea-person who saw the time traveler then destroyed the time machine and trapped the time traveler because if he were to go back, she and her underwater civilization would no longer exist due to the evidence of a nuclear annihilation.

It's a very short story, probably a few pages long.

I would love it if someone could help me find the title of the story.

Comment: When was "years ago?"  Check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details.

Comment: Around 5 years ago.

Comment: If I've got this straight, the sea-person believes that if the time traveler returns to the past, there *will* be a nuclear war in the past -- but if he doesn't return to his native era, there definitely *won't* be a nuclear war in the past? Do you remember what makes her so sure that just stopping the time traveler will make all the difference in preventing such a war?

Comment: Very sorry if it wasn't clear. If the time traveler returns to the past, he would have proof that a nuclear war existed that destroyed the earth, thereby preventing it from happening and erasing the sea person and her society from existence. By destroying the time machine, it guarantees that her society will still exist because no one would have proof that a nuclear war existed. This may also explain your latter point as well.

Comment: Ah. I think I see, now. When you wrapped up the original post by saying "would no longer exist due to the evidence of a nuclear annihilation," I thought that meant something along these lines: "If the nuclear war happens in the past, it will leave long-term scars on the planet which will then prevent her civilization, in its present location, from ever existing." But I asked for clarification because I was not at all sure that I had grasped the subtleties of the situation you were describing -- and it turns out I hadn't. I'm afraid I don't recognize the story, though.

Comment: That's fine. It may be a very obscure story, hence why I can't find it anywhere.